# C++ 2d array writing into multiple places

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a console C++ chess game and whenever I write into my board array at places like
07 it will put info in other places like 10.

I'm also getting buffer overruns warnings on `Board[0][0] = 'C';`

```
void Setup(char Board[7][7])
{
    // sets all board spaces to a period
    for (int a = 0; a < 8; ++a)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 8; ++b)
        {
            Board[a][b] = '.';
        }
    }

    //place pieces
    {
        Board[0][0] = 'C';
        Board[0][7] = 'C';
        Board[7][0] = 'c';
        Board[7][7] = 'c';
        Board[0][1] = 'H';
        Board[0][6] = 'H';
        Board[7][1] = 'h';
        Board[7][6] = 'h';
        Board[0][2] = 'B';
        Board[0][5] = 'B';
        Board[7][2] = 'b';
        Board[7][5] = 'b';
        Board[0][3] = 'Q';
        Board[0][4] = 'K';
        Board[7][3] = 'k';
        Board[7][4] = 'q';

        for (int p = 0; p < 8; ++p)
        {
            Board[1][p] = 'P';
            Board[6][p] = 'p';
        }
    }
    cout << "setup complete" << endl;
}

void Display(char Board[7][7])
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 8; ++a)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 8; ++b)
        {
            cout << Board[a][b] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    static char Board[7][7];
    int Winner = 0;

    Setup(Board);
    while (Winner == 0)
    {
        //turn1
        //turn2
        Display(Board);
        break;
    }
    //winner
    return 0;
}
```

this outputs:

```
setup complete
C H B Q K B H P
P P P P P P P P
P . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . p
p p p p p p p p
p h b k q b h c
```

The pawns are never written into place like 07 but somehow they show up there.
Honestly I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try changing your index operations in the for loops from `++p` to `p++`

Comment: nope, didnt do anything :(

Comment: Off-by-one error. When you declare an `array[n]` the valid indexes are `0 -> n-1`. So if you want to access indexes `0-7` you need an array with `8-elements`.

Comment: What @DavidC.Rankin said: Declare the array with how many elements to you need (it's extent). Then use the array  `[0, extent-1]` (inclusive). or `[0, extent)` (exclusive), same thing.

Comment: You are using the wrong syntax for your function parameter. You can pass a 2d array by pointer or reference, which would be: ````void Setup(char (*Board)[8][8])```` or ````void Setup(char (&Board)[8][8])````. Otherwise you will run into a pointer decay problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is considering `Baord` as `7x7` array. In provided code `char Board[7][7]` should be `char Board[8][8]`.

Keep in mind the following, while you are working with array:

- *Declaration/Definition:* When you declarer/define an array at that time the value in `[]` is *size of the array*. e.g. `int testArray[10];` Here we defined an array of size `10` which have index from `0` to `9`
- *Operation on array elements:* When you try to use the array and perform some operation, the the value in `[]` is *index in the array*. e.g. `testArray[5] = 20;` Here we have changed the value of `6th element`(which is at index 5 as index starts from `0` and from `1`) to `20`.
- *Element and index:* As mention in above lines, `Index in array starts from 0`. So 1st element will be at index `0`, 2nd at index `1` and so on i.e. `Nth element` will be at index `N-1`

Following is corrected code. you can [see it working here](https://ideone.com/4gOrgw):

```
#include <iostream>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 8
using namespace std;

void Setup(char Board[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE])
{
    // sets all board spaces to a period
    for (int a = 0; a < ARRAY_SIZE; ++a)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < ARRAY_SIZE; ++b)
        {
            Board[a][b] = '.';
        }
    }

    //place peices
    {
        Board[0][0] = 'C';
        Board[0][7] = 'C';
        Board[7][0] = 'c';
        Board[7][7] = 'c';
        Board[0][1] = 'H';
        Board[0][6] = 'H';
        Board[7][1] = 'h';
        Board[7][6] = 'h';
        Board[0][2] = 'B';
        Board[0][5] = 'B';
        Board[7][2] = 'b';
        Board[7][5] = 'b';
        Board[0][3] = 'Q';
        Board[0][4] = 'K';
        Board[7][3] = 'k';
        Board[7][4] = 'q';

        for (int p = 0; p < ARRAY_SIZE; ++p)
        {
            Board[1][p] = 'P';
            Board[6][p] = 'p';
        }
    }
    cout << "setup complete" << endl;
}

void Display(char Board[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE])
{
    for (int a = 0; a < ARRAY_SIZE; ++a)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < ARRAY_SIZE; ++b)
        {
            cout << Board[a][b] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    static char Board[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];
    int Winner = 0;

    Setup(Board);
    while (Winner == 0)
    {
        //turn1
        //turn2
        Display(Board);
        break;
    }
    //winner
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create an array:

```
    int foo[4];
```

the number 4 means you will have 4 `int`s, which you can access using:

```
    foo[0]
    foo[1]
    foo[2]
    foo[3]
```

So when you create `char Board[7][7]` with two sevens, you get a 7x7 chess board (because 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 are 7 numbers in total, not 8), and therefore not a 8x8 chess board.

So just replace any `Board[7][7]` by `Board[8][8]` and you will be fine.